# Deploying Excel Add-ins and Workbooks

Tags: excel-addins

I have developed an add-in (xlam) for Excel 2013 (some users have 2010) that contains half a dozen macros.

I used to load it from UNC path on the server and that worked great, but every time I need to update it, all the users have to quit excel because it's locked. There are now too many users in multiple buildings, so this is approach is no longer viable. I need to find a way to deploy new version of the macro-enabled workbook and the add-in, so that it works on local PC's.

We use Microsoft SCCM at work, so I figured, no problems, I'll just deploy the add-in to the users' local add-in directory (%APPDATA%/Microst/Addins). This works fine. The problem is when I send them an updated version of the macro enabled worksheet that uses the add-in (which changes fairly frequently), %appdata% has been expanded to my user name and of course the path to the add-in is not valid on someone else's machine.

I figured, no problems, I'll make a common dir on everyone's machine (C:\Program Files\CompanyName\Addins) and install the add-in there, so that the path is valid on all machines. I open my workbook, load the add-in and test it. Works great.

I have a DisplayVersions macro that shows the correct version and the path I just loaded the addin from (C:\Program Files\CompanyName\Addins) as the Addin path.

I save the worksheet, quit Excel. Next time I open it, it's trying to load it from my %appdata%/Microsoft/Addins directory and of course it doesn't exist there. It never asked me if I wanted to copy it there.

This is driving me mad. There HAS to be a way to deploy an add-in and a worksheet, so it will work from all local PC's

Anyone got any suggestions

Regards

Mark

Comment: "%appdata% has been expanded to my user name" - If you use an installer to install on a end user's machine %APPDATA% should expand to that of the end user's machine, and not your machine's APPDATA. Will that help.

Comment: Not quite sure if Microsoft SCCM  can be used to pick the %APPDATA% of the end user's machine, though.

Comment: It installs in correct place. Problem is the macros in the workbook have expanded %Appdata% to my local path

Comment: Would be good if you could share the relevant source code.